# Problems getting matrix to display

Tags: java, matrix

this is my 1st time asking for help for programming. Anywho, I need to write a program which find the determinant of a matrix (The determinant code will be made on a later date). Problem being is that I am having trouble getting my matrix to display. It seems that I have the array written correctly, but the output would skip the for loops to write the matrix. Would there be any changes that needs to be done or if theres a certain way that I need to set my array to determine determinants?

```
public class DetProg {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);

    Random mNum = new Random();
    System.out.print("Enter matrix size: ");
    int num = a.nextInt();
    int numX = num;
    int numY = num;
    int [][] matNN = new int [numX] [numY];
    int det = 0;// 0 is the placeholder until det method is inputted.
    int n = mNum.nextInt(100)+1;
    if (num >= 2)
    {            
        for(int x = 0; x >= numX; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y >= numY; y++)
            {
                matNN [x][y] = n;
                System.out.println(matNN[x][y] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Determinant of a matrix is " + det);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Incorrect matrix size. Exiting...");
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the loop condition...

Answer (score 0):

In your **loops**, you are making mistake in placing condition. you wrote **x >= numX** and **y >= numY** which will not be satisfied to even start the loop, because your x and y are equal to 0 in the start. it should be as:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= numX; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y <= numY; y++)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to change your loop conditions.

```
for (int x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
```

this will result in proper assignment of values in an array and after this you can proceed further for your code of `Determinant` of a matrix.